# Mariadb Galera cluster empty set

Tags: mysql, mariadb, errors, galera, multi-master

I am playing around with a MariaDB Galera Master Master Cluster and I have some issues which I do not understand.
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0

```
[galera]
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
binlog_format=ROW
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.2.67'
wsrep_node_name='KVM-1'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=repl_user:PASS
```

On the other nodes

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0

[galera]
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
binlog_format=ROW
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://IP_ADDR_MAIN_NODE,OTHER_NODES_ADDRS"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.2.68'
wsrep_node_name='KVM-2'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=repl_user:PASS
```

when i login to mysql and query for

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_size';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Am i missing anything?

Comment: what does the log say?

Comment: show status like 'slave%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Slave_heartbeat_period     | 0.000 |
| Slave_open_temp_tables     | 0     |
| Slave_received_heartbeats  | 0     |
| Slave_retried_transactions | 0     |
| Slave_running              | OFF   |
+----------------------------+-------+

Comment: [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--wsrep-new-cluster'
180517 15:53:44 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: Which MariaDB version is this? Which Linux and version? Which MariaDB related packages have you installed? How are you trying to start the MariaDB instances?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> stop all nodes.
> On first node run -> galera_new_cluster 
> Once it is started.
> Then on Second node run - > service mysql start
> ```